# No horizontal line for bounty tab in private mode

Tags: bug, design, bounties, localization

Main pages for SO sites: [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) opened in browser's private mode does not contain horizontal line for the bounty tab:

> [image: pt]

> [image: ru]

> [image: es]

Being logged in line is visible:

> [image: pt ok]

Tested in Firefox 56.0.1 for Windows. In Google Chrome page looks fine.

Comment: In SO, the issue is in Activity tab too - [Alignment issue in the Activity tab in Firefox browser](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351943/2451726)